# Кэшируемость тега details для фильтра на сайте

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

В теме в принципе наверно все понятно, но опишу подробней.
На сайте через плагин сделал фильтр для товаров, много пунктов, поэтому основные пункты (цена, по бренду) сделал открытыми всегда, а вторичные (по размеру, по типу) скрыл тегом details.
Проблема:
При выборе вторичного пункта в фильтре (чекбокса) и нажатии кнопки "Подбор", страница обновляется и тег details обратно закрывается, что очень неудобно.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при обновлении страницы, открытый тег details оставался открытым, закрытый - закрытым. Как то через кэш, но как, не могу найти инфы.

Comment: самый легкий способ при фильтрации не перегружать страницу...ну а так в вашем распоряжении `sessionStorage`, `localStorage`, `cookie`. Ну и еще зависит способ загрузки самих данных на странице...например можно сделать чтобы фильт передавался на сервер и он его обрабатывал (после обработки обратно клиенту).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В примере ниже показана работа с [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), но он имеет схожий интерфейс с [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

```js
// Список узлов `NodeList` из `details` (скрытых данных, спойлеров).
const DETAILS = document.querySelectorAll('details');

// Хранилище состояний.
let stateDetails = [];

// Если список узлов `details` не пуст.
if (DETAILS.length) {
  // Инициируем начальное состояние.
  stateDetails = initStateDetails(DETAILS);
}

// Перебираем узлы `details`.
DETAILS.forEach(function(item, index) {
  // Открываем/закрываем `details`.
  item.open = stateDetails[index].open;

  // Регистрируем функцию-обработчика.
  // Т.е. при раскрытии обновляем запись в хранилище.
  item.addEventListener('toggle', function(event) {
    stateDetails.splice(index, 1, {
      index: index,
      open: event.target.open
    });

    // Обязательно обновляем массив в хранилище.
    saveStateDetails();
  });
});

// Загрузка состояния для всех `details`.
function initStateDetails(details) {
  let result;

  try {
    // Загружаем состояние + отлавливаем
    // синтаксические ошибки при парсинге
    result = loadStateDetails();

    // Если в хранилище пусто, либо количество в хранилище
    // отличается от количества на странице, то:
    if (!result.length || details.length !== result.length) {
      throw 'Bad data in state for details.';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // а) создать новый массив;
    result = [];

    // б) записать новые данные в массив;
    details.forEach(function(item, index) {
      result.push({
        index: index,
        open: item.open
      });
    });
  } finally {
    // Возвращаем результат загрузки данных.
    return result;
  }
}

// Загрузка состояния для всех `details`.
function loadStateDetails() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('stateDetails'));
}

// Сохранение состояния для всех `details`.
function saveStateDetails() {
  localStorage.setItem('stateDetails', JSON.stringify(stateDetails));
}
```

```css
details {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: .5em .5em 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

summary {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: -.5em -.5em 0;
  padding: .5em;
}

details[open] {
  padding: .5em;
}

details[open] summary {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Some details</summary>
  <p>More info about the details.</p>
</details>

<details open>
  <summary>Even more details</summary>
  <p>Я открыт при первой загрузке.</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Some details</summary>
  <p>More info about the details.</p>
</details>
```

---

**NB** Причина того, почему не работает в [снипете](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/why-are-we-disallowed-to-use-html5-local-storage-on-code-snippets).